# append NSMutable Strings in for loop

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
//viewdidload
{
str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
str2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
}//

for (int pq=1; pq<=temp; pq++) 
{
str1 =  [NSMutableString stringWithString:[documentManager wholeTextForPage:pq] ] ;
[self.str2 appendString:str1];
NSLog(@"content of page chumma1:  %@",str1);
}
NSLog(@"cwhole text:  %@",str2
```

**Here str1 returns different string on each iteration. am trying to append each and every string returned by str1 to str2. but the str2 returns only one string returned by str1 on first iteration. strings returned on others iterations are not append to str2. Please help me to find a way to sole this. Thanks in advance.

Thanks & Regards
VEERA **

Comment: I think your for loop is wrong.

Comment: seem you are just voting your question as this question is closed then too you got Votes +4 that impossible....

Answer (score 0):

```
Use stringByAppendingString see example:
But str2 should declare NSString
```

**Update:**

```
NSMutableString *str1 = [NSMutableString string];
NSString *str2 = @"";

for (int pq=1; pq<=temp; pq++) 
{
    str1 =  [NSMutableString stringWithString:[documentManager wholeTextForPage:pq] ] ;
    str2 = [str2 stringByAppendingString:str1];
}
```

This will append all data from str1 to str2.

Comment: :(.. Incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct NSString *' , expected 'struct NSMutableString' -  WARNING

Comment: Declare str2 as NSString

Comment: :(. same output...str2 returns only the string from first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
....
for (int pq=0; pq < temp; pq++)  {
    str1 =  [NSMutableString stringWithString:[documentManager wholeTextForPage:pq] ] ;
    [self.str2 appendString:str1];
    NSLog(@"content of page chumma1:  %@",str1);
}

NSLog(@"cwhole text:  %@",str2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this for appending string:

```
str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (int pq=1; pq<=temp; pq++) 
{
  str1 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithString:[documentManager wholeTextForPage:pq]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *str1= [NSMutableString new];
    for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
        [str1 appendString:@"Hi "];
    }   
    NSLog(@"%@",str1);
```

Your code may not work because appendString:(NSString*)str  not NSMutableString. so use NSString.

for you code try this

```
for (int pq=1; pq<=temp; pq++)
    [self.str2 appendString:[documentManager wholeTextForPage:pq]];
```

Comment: [documentManager wholeTextForPage:pq] will return NSString. Str2 is NSmutable String. so that appendString won't work without casting. self.str2 also not works.:(

Comment: `- (void)appendString:(NSString *)`  no need to typecast, if you want to typecast you may

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way ....

```
NSMutableString *str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
NSMutableString *str2 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

for(int pq=1; pq<temp; pq++)
{
    str1 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:[documentManager wholeTextForPage:pq]];
    str2 = (NSMutableString *)[str2 stringByAppendingFormat:str1];
    NSLog(@"content of page chumma1:  %@",str1);
}

NSLog(@"cwhole text:  %@",str2);
```